# jquery click on href show div not working

Tags: jquery, href, show

I have tried this script but nothing happend when running it.

```html
<a href="#sign_up">sign up</a>

<script>
$('a[href = "#sign_up"]').click(function(){
    $("#signup").show();
    $("#page").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You just need to do `$("#signup").click(function(){`

Comment: check the div id is it `#signup` or `#sign_up`.

Comment: Your code works, but you need to include the jQuery library. Here is a jsfiddle with your exact code working: http://jsfiddle.net/80aewwz6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this:

```
$('a[href="#sign_up"]').click(function(e){ // remove the spaces
   e.preventDefault(); // pervent the jump
   $("#sign_up").show(); // check this id
   $("#page").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<a href="#sign_up" id="sign_up">sign up</a>

<script>
$('#sign_up').click(function(){
    $("#signup").show();
    $("#page").hide();
    });
</script>
```